# virtualenv selection menu shows only the first few virtualenvs

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a number of virtualenvs, currently 40, but when I try to select one via the drop-down menu in emacs, it shows only the first 30 or so. Is there a way to get a scrollbar attached to that menu, so I can find the later ones, too?

I have so far not managed virtualenvs with Emacs at all, it just picked up the pre-existing virtualenvs. I have Emacs 26.1, Elpy 1.28.0, and anaconda-mode 20200129.1718. I am not sure how they play together, but in python-mode, I get a drop-down menu with my virtualenvs, which shows the first few, and the rest just seems to hang off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details: what emacs package(s) are you using to manage these virtualenvs? What drop-down menu are you talking about, i.e. what do you do to generate it?

Comment: I have so far not managed virtualenvs with Emacs at all, it just picked up the pre-existing virtualenvs. I have Emacs 26.1, Elpy 1.28.0, and anaconda-mode 20200129.1718. I am not sure how they play together, but in python-mode, I get a drop-down menu with my virtualenvs, which shows the first few, and the rest just seems to hang off the screen.

Comment: @tmlpy: Please put into your *question* those details you added in your *comment*

Comment: @Stefan: I've expanded the question as desired.